# in power shell I have a variable which contains a number I want to add some dots (.) to the number how I can do this?

Tags: powershell, match, invoke-webrequest

here is a part of my script in powershell

```
$Uri = 'https://codecguide.com/download_k-lite_codec_pack_basic.htm'
$web = Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri $uri 
( $downloadurl=$web.Links |Where-Object href -Like "*.exe" |Select-Object -First 1 -expand href )
$downloadurl -match "(\d{4,})" 
( $latestversion = "$($Matches[1])" )
```

and the `$lateestversion` is 1730 , How I can change this number to look like 17.3.0 ???
thanks in advance

Comment: How do you know that 1730 = 17.3.0, and not, say, 1.73.0? or 1.7.30?

Comment: because when I download the software the software version is written like 17.3.0 :) anyway do you know how to convert it like this?

Comment: "the software version is written like 17.3.0" - where? Do you see this when you do `Get-Item resultingfile.exe |% VersionInfo`? If so, grab the version from the `VersionInfo` object instead of trying to guess :)

Comment: I need the version number before downloading the file and having it on the PC so I can not use % VersionInfo , and it is written like 17.3.0 on the website and as I have seen the last versions it is always like (  \d\d\.\d\.\d )

Comment: Save the file with a temp name, get version info and rename the file?

Comment: thanks a lot for your help and time , but I should not download it before checking whether this $latestversion ( \d\d\.\d\.\d ) exists in the directory or not, if not then I will download it. so right now I just want to change that number to follow this ( \d\d\.\d\.\d ) pattern

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is not possible to do in a reliable way. When the file is renamed in such a way that version number dots are simply removed, one cannot recover the lost information.

As Mathias commented, one cannot tell stripped-dot version number of `1730` apart from `17.3.0`, `1.7.30`, `1.7.3.0`, `173.0`, `17.30`, or `1.73.0`.

When you stuff 5 or more characters in a string that's only four characters long, you are going to have a collission. It's a mathematical fact, see the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) for further explanation.

What *might* be possible is to recover the dots, iff you know that the version follows a certain pattern. For example, if there *always* are two digits for the minor version and one for the build number, you can insert the lost dots. But as said, that requires information that one needs to have in advance.

Comment: thanks for your answer but no information has been lost and as I have checked the pattern of the version is always like ( \d\d\.\d\.\d ) ,I  just want the content of $latestversion follow the pattern ( \d\d\.\d\.\d )